# Automating Code Reconciliation Process?

Tags: git, tfs, devops

What is the best way to automate the forward integration & reverse integration process across the release hives?

Version Control System: git (But in some areas we have TFS)

Comment: Could you specify more about your query? Which version of TFS are you using? Do you use Release tab for your release?

Answer (score 0):

1. With Git version control, each developer has a copy of the source repository on their dev machine. When you need to switch contexts, you can create a private local branch. You can quickly switch from one branch to another to pivot among different variations of your codebase. Later, you can merge, publish, or dispose of the branch.
2. When undoing changes in Git, first decide what type of changes you are looking to undo. These changes fall into three categories:

   - Discard uncommitted changes to a file, bringing the file back to the
     version in the last commit.
   - Reset your local branch to a previous commit.
   - Revert changes pushed to a remote branch and shared with others.

Details check: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/undo

3. When you want to build or release your project, you can create a build/release definition in TFS, more information check: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/create